# How to reverse word by word in a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, reverse, ecmascript-5

I'm writing the logic for reverse word by word in string javascript.

But I'm thinking my code is more lengthy so, I'm looking for good answer.

```
Ex :- I/p- Hi how are you // o/p- iH woh era uoy
```

```js
function ReverseString(val) {
  var op = "",
    iCount = -1;
  for (let i = 0; i <= val.length; i++) {
    if (val[i] != " " && i != val.length)
      continue;
    for (let j = i - 1; j > iCount; j--)
      op += val[j];
    if (i != val.length)
      op += " ";
    iCount = i;
  }
  return op;
}

console.log(ReverseString("Hi how are you"));
```

Comment: Clarify what do you mean by "pre-define method". Sounds like a pointless requirement with no basis.

Comment: Given your edit: `Answer should not be contain any predefined method. Like- (split (), reverse () ..)` then this code is about as succinct as you're going to get. It's ugly though. I'm not sure why you want the (frankly ridiculous) no methods rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution.

```html
<script>
rev=(val)=>{
return val.split("").reverse().join("").split(" ").reverse().join(" ")
}
console.log(rev('Hi how are you'))
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to split the string by whitespace to have an array of words, then reverse those words within the array using `map()`, like this:

```js
function ReverseString(val) {
  return val.split(/\s/g).map(w => w.split('').reverse().join('')).join(' ');
}
console.log(ReverseString("Hi how are you"));
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is to seperate you words in an array using split()

Then for each word, split the letters and use the reverse function and re-join them.

At least, re-join the word

```js
const str = "Hi how are you";

let str_reversed = str.split(' ');// put each word in an array

str_reversed = str_reversed.map(word => word.split('').reverse().join('')); // for each word, we put each letter in array, reverse them and then re-join them

str_reversed = str_reversed.join(' '); // rejoin the word
console.log(str_reversed);
```

Answer (score 1):

A one line solution to reverse each word maintaining the order:

```
var original = 'Hi how are you';

var reversed = original.split("").reverse().join("").split(" ").reverse().join(" ")
```

o/p: "iH woh era uoy"

Answer (score 1):

```
let str = 'Hi how are you';

let reverse = str
        .split("")
        .reverse()
        .join("")
        .split(" ")
        .reverse()
        .join(" ")
    );
```